# Read csv file in spark of varying columns

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I would like to read csv file into dataframe in spark using Scala.
My csv file has first record which has three columns and remaining records have 5 columns. My csv file does not come with column names. I have mentioned here's for understanding

```
Ex:
I'dtype  date             recordsCount
0          13-02-2015  300
I'dtype  date          type      location.     locationCode
1         13-02-2015.    R.          USA.            Us
1.        13-02-2015.    T.          London.      Lon
```

My question is how I will read this file into dataframe,as first and remaining rows have different columns.
The solution what I tried is read file as rdd and filter out header record and then convert remaining records into dataframe.
Is there any better solution for ? Please help me

Comment: Can any of the last two columns be null?

Comment: looks like in addition to having two different column lengths, you have different columns altogether, with the third column being either recordsCount, or type. That makes things a bit more complicated, and should probably be noted in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the files as raw text, and then use case classes, `Either` instances, and pattern matching to sort out what goes where. Example of that below.

```
case class Col3(c1: Int, c2: String, c3: Int)
case class Col5(c1: Int, c2: String, c5_col3: String, c4:String, c5: String)
case class Header(value: String)

type C3 = Either[Header, Col3]
type C5 = Either[Header, Col5]

// assume sqlC & sc created 

val path = "tmp.tsv"
val rdd = sc.textFile(path)

val eitherRdd: RDD[Either[C3, C5]] = rdd.map{s =>
  val spl = s.split("\t")
  spl.length match{
    case 3 =>
      val res = Try{
        Col3(spl(0).toInt, spl(1), spl(2).toInt)
      }
      res match{
        case Success(c3) => Left(Right(c3))
        case Failure(_) => Left(Left(Header(s)))
      }
    case 5 =>
      val res = Try{
        Col5(spl(0).toInt, spl(1), spl(2), spl(3), spl(4))
      }
      res match{
        case Success(c5) => Right(Right(c5))
        case Failure(_) => Right(Left(Header(s)))
      }
    case _ => throw new Exception("fail")
  }
}

val rdd3 = eitherRdd.flatMap(_.left.toOption)
val rdd3Header = rdd3.flatMap(_.left.toOption).collect().head
val df3 = sqlC.createDataFrame(rdd3.flatMap(_.right.toOption))

val rdd5 = eitherRdd.flatMap(_.right.toOption)
val rdd5Header = rdd5.flatMap(_.left.toOption).collect().head
val df5 = sqlC.createDataFrame(rdd5.flatMap(_.right.toOption))

df3.show()

df5.show()
```

Tested with simple tsv below:

```
col1    col2    col3
0   sfd 300
1   asfd    400
col1    col2    col4    col5    col6
2   pljdsfn R   USA Us
3   sad T   London  Lon
```

which gives output

```
+---+----+---+
| c1|  c2| c3|
+---+----+---+
|  0| sfd|300|
|  1|asfd|400|
+---+----+---+

+---+-------+-------+------+---+
| c1|     c2|c5_col3|    c4| c5|
+---+-------+-------+------+---+
|  2|pljdsfn|      R|   USA| Us|
|  3|    sad|      T|London|Lon|
+---+-------+-------+------+---+
```

For simplicity sake, I have ignored the date formatting, simply storing those fields as Strings. however it would not be much more complicated to add a date parser to get you a proper column type.

Likewise, I have relied on parsing failure to indicate a header row. You may substitute different logic if either the parsing would not fail, or if a more complicated determination must be made. Similarly, more complicated logic would be needed to differentiate between different record types of the same length, or which may contain (escaped) split character

Comment: Than you so much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack but here is a solution to ignore the first line of the file.

```scala
val cols = Array("dtype", "date", "type", "location", "locationCode")
val schema = new StructType(cols.map(n => StructField(n ,StringType, true)))
spark.read
    .schema(schema) // we specify the schema
    .option("header", true) // and tell spark that there is a header
    .csv("path/file.csv")
```

The first line is the header, but the schema is specified. The first line is thus ignored.

Comment: I do not want to ignore header. I need header for further processing.